# React Redux and Should Component Update Optimisation

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

### **Code:**

Root Component

```
    <Provider store={Store}>
       <AppLayoutContainer>
           {this.props.template}
       </AppLayoutContainer>
    </Provider>
```

AppLayoutContainer

```
....some code

  return(
    <div className={`AppLayoutContainer`}>
       <Modal isOpen={isModalShown} .... />
       <div>{children}</div>
     </div>
  )

....some code

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { app } = state;
  return {
    isModalShown: app.isModalShown
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppLayoutContainer);
```

---

### Problem:

Every time when Applayoutcontainer get `isModalShown` from Redux, My whole app is re-rendering and it's very bad. All I need is re-render only the Modal component and don't touch my `children`. I think it's possible with `ShouldComponentUpdate` method, but I really don't understand how to do it.

Any ideas ? I know that someone did it in his project and can advise some Best Practise for this. Thanks

---

### UPDATE:

Read all answers and YES it's good solution to connect Modal with Store,
but what if

1) I want Modal component be pure (re usable) like  or  components ?

2) I need to use `isModalShown` in AppLayoutContainer ?

```
return(
    <div className={`AppLayoutContainer`}>
       <Modal isOpen={isModalShown} .... />
       <div>{children}</div>
     </div>
  )
```

---

### UPDATE 2.0

Thank You for the Answer but what can I do with this

The main problem that I need to blur all my content when I show `Modal` component, as I know `blur()` can be applied only on content to work (not on absolute position div that overlay my content)and do it like this

```
return(
        <div className={`AppLayoutContainer`}>
           <Modal isOpen={isModalShown} .... />
           <div className={isModalShown ? 'blured' : null }>{children}</div>
         </div>
      )
```

But my whole app will re-render every time when I show up my `Modal`, I need to freeze it. The solution with build the container for `child` and do `shouldcomponentupdate` here isn't good, how can React compare the Whole components ?? It only compare non immutable fields in props.

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should do is not pass the `isModal` in the `AppLayoutContainer`'s `mapStateToProps` function, but instead `connect` the `Modal` itself.

Any results from `mapStateToProps` that change will cause the `connect`ed component to rerender. In your case, your `mapStateToProps` `connect`ed to `AppLayoutContainer` returns the value of `isModalShown` which causes your `AppLayoutContainer` to rerender.

If you want to only rerender the `Modal` itself then just

```
export default connect(state => ({isOpen: state.app.isModalShown}))(Modal)
```

in your `Modal` file, or in a separate file if you like that better.

Also remove the `isModalShown` prop from the `AppLayoutContainer` because you don't need it *and* because leaving it there means the `AppLayoutContainer` will still rerender every time `isModalShown` changes (which is what you're trying to fix).

**Update** regarding question updates:

Issue 1:

You can have a pure `Modal`

```
export default function Modal(props) {
  return <span>Open={props.isOpen}</span>;
}
```

You can then make a specific Modal for a particular use:

```
import Modal from './modal';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default const AppLayoutModal = connect(state => ({isOpen: state.app.isModalShown}))(Modal);
```

You can do this many times for all kinds of separate modals. In fact this is why is a good idea to use pure components.

Issue 2:

If you want to use `isModalShown` in `AppLayoutContainer` then you have some choices:

- Just use it. React always renders an entire component. Because it's just one render method. It updates the DOM, if any, more fine-grained but if you want less stuff to render when something changes then it's up to you to make your render functions small. If you leave the component large then the whole thing will rerender.
- You can chop down your components into smaller ones so they can be rendered separately. You can make a small component to only use `isModalShown` via `connect` directly so the large `AppLayoutContainer` doesn't change. Child components can and do update independently from their parent components.

**Update 2**

To blur your entire app, just add a class to the app. Child components will not rerender. Redux prevents the children from rendering because it notices the children aren't using `isModalShown`. The resulting React element is the exact same object (a reference) as the previous render. React sees that it's the same element and knows not to update the whole tree. This works because React elements are immutable. Your whole app will not rerender. In fact, React will *only* add or remove the class from the class attribute.

If your children do not use Redux to prevent the render from walking up the tree, then you can wrap the children in a Redux connected component. Alternatively, you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent the render of the children.

Bare React asks you to send data down the tree from the root. Redux asks you to inject data into the tree right where it's  needed. The latter has the benefit that nothing else needs to be rerendered. Without Redux, the entire tree would *always* be rerendered on every change except for when a component uses `shouldComponentUpdate` to stop the propagation. That, however, stops the render not just for the current component, but also for all children. Redux eliminates this because child components can have their props updated without the parent's cooperation or knowledge.

In short: use Redux everywhere for speed gains everywhere.

Comment: Yes, ur answer is good, but what if I need to go deepe, update my Question for you

Comment: Thanks, I read it and do just like u said `just add a class to the app` (`UPDATE 2.0` code  in my Question, but without Modal component) But when I add `isModalShown` props in AppLayoutContainer and applied it to `<div>{children}</div>` all my children in App re rendering, every time  I saw there rendering  in my React inspector. OR I don't fully understand Your solution and do something wrong.

Comment: Are those children Redux-connected?

Comment: Nope, just there parent. AppLayoutContainer is the parent of all components in app.

Answer (score 1):

You have different strategies possible here.

1. Use `shouldComponentUpdate` in your child components (very messy and inelegant in this case) ;
2. Connect the Modal component to the store instead of `AppLayoutContainer` ;
3. Store `isModalShown` in the state of `Modal`, not in the global state.

When possible, the last solution is often the more appropriate IMHO. You keep the UI state in the related component, because you don't need very often to be aware of this in other components.

```
class Modal extends Component {
  state = {
    isModalShown: false,
  };

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In the case you need to know `isModalShown` in other places, you should connect the `Modal` component instead of `AppLayoutContainer`.

```
export default connect((state) => ({
  isModalShown: state.app.isModalShown,
}))(Modal)
```

Comment: It is my understanding that all state should preferably be moved to Redux and all Components should preferably be converted to stateless and/or pure functional components. Time travel, for instance, doesn't work well if a number of components are just not playing along. A modal dialog that stays open when you rewind time can destroy any benefits you get from time travel.

Comment: Well it really depends on your app, but in the cases I encountered, it's pretty useless to store UI-related state (like open/close a dropdown component, or manage the focus state of a form input) with Redux. I tend to prefer to think my app as Presentational/Container instead of Stateful/Stateless components.

Answer (score 0):

I think DDS and Anthony Dugois have the right of it, but if those are not the answers you're looking for, you could always pipe `children` into a new component, and use `shouldComponentUpdate` there.